# using Stylus to write a CSS file to be served by nginx

Tags: node.js, stylus

in a `node.js` environment, instead of `stylus` generating the `.css` each time, would like to write the `.css` file to a directory to be served by `nginx`.

seems that versioning part of name, eg, `client-<unixTime>.css`, then `nginx` will be happy and page caching will work correctly.

are there any existent tools available for helping with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did not realize that `stylus` was also an executable that can be run one-time or as a demon.  in either case will convert the `.styl` files to `.css`, putting them in the directory of your choice.

in `node.js`, to get the executable

```
sudo npm install stylus -g
```

for me, using `stylus` this way is much preferred because of the way inflexibility of the `stylus middleware`.  rather than address that, using executable.  this also keeps the development and production `node` server more closely aligned, but does not solve the versioning issue.

---

here is my function that compiles one file (synchronous):

```
var stylus = require('stylus'),
    nib = require('nib');

// compile stylus
exports.css = function( fn, out ) {
  var buf = fs.readFileSync( fn, 'utf8' );
  var oldCode = ( fs.existsSync( out ) ) ? fs.readFileSync( out, 'utf8' ) : 'none';
  stylus( buf )
    .set( 'filename', fn )
    .use( nib() )
    .render( function(err,newCode) {
      if( err ) throw( 'stylus err: '+err );
      if( oldCode != newCode ) {
        console.log( 'stylus: creating '+out );
        fs.writeFileSync( out, newCode, 'utf8' );
      }
    });
};
```

(after compiling I gzip using non-current `gz` files using `compress-buffer` (sync)

Comment: any idea how to make the executable compile a styl file that includes nib?

Comment: @stream7: I have added the compile function I wrote to the answer.  let me know if this is adequate.  lol